# When an 'integer-complex' always is transformed to an 'integer-complex'?

Tags: complex-analysis

I tried Mobius transformations $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ for several $z∈ \mathbb{Z}+i\mathbb{Z}$ and it seems that even if $M=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix} \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, not any 'integer-complex' ($z∈ \mathbb{Z}+i\mathbb{Z}$) transforms to a 'integer-complex' and vice-versa. If I am not mistaken after evaluation of $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ even lines can be transformed to circles and and vice-versa.

My question is, for what subset of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, a $z∈ \mathbb{Z}+i\mathbb{Z}$ *always* is transformed to a $w∈ \mathbb{Z}+i\mathbb{Z}$ by transformations $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$? In other words, a set that transforms lattices to lattices?

Comment: For the record, the elements of the set $\mathbf{Z}[i]:=\mathbf{Z}+i\mathbf{Z}$ are called *Gaussian integers*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply nominator and denominator of $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ by $\overline{cz+d}$ for $a,b,c,d\in \Bbb{Z}$ to see that we necessarily need
$$
\frac{ad-bc}{c^2+d^2}=\frac{1}{c^2+d^2}\in \Bbb{Z}.
$$
So we need $c^2+d^2=1$ as one necessary condition. Now you can finish.